Building ro2 from source failed due to tf2_ros_py
I'm trying to build ROS2 from source on ubuntu 20.04 on parallels on apple silicon, but I'm getting this error
Starting >>> tf2_ros_py
--- stderr: rclcpp                                                        
c++: fatal error: Killed signal terminated program cc1plus
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [test/rclcpp/CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/build.make:63: test/rclcpp/CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/test_node.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3215: test/rclcpp/CMakeFiles/test_node.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< rclcpp [46.7s, exited with code 2]
Aborted  <<< tf2_ros_py [0.39s]                               

Summary: 166 packages finished [1min 35s]
  1 package failed: rclcpp
  1 package aborted: tf2_ros_py
  1 package had stderr output: rclcpp
  177 packages not processed
```

